# Swagger schema properties ignored - why?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, redoc

I'm trying to build a simple Swagger model:

```
PlayerConfig:
  type: object
  required:
    - kind
    - player_id
  properties:
    kind:
      type: string
      example: PlayerConfig
    player_id:
      type: string
      example: "foo"
      description: "bar"

sports_config:
  oneOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerConfig'
  discriminator:
    propertyName: kind
```

For some reason the generated HTML does not show the `player_id`'s `example` field. This makes me think I'm not doing this correctly.s

So the question is if using a model as a type can in fact be done as I'm trying to do. `example` field does get rendered if its parent is `parameters:` instead of `properties:`.

Update: I read `Object and Property Examples` section on https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/ and it seems like my code snippet should have worked.

Update #2: I actually downloaded `redoc-cli` (which is a CLI tool for OpenAPI -> html bundle) and took a sample spec from Swagger Editor that has `example` field under `properties` that mimics my problem and it looks like it's expected (see the screenshot I attached):
[image]

Comment: What documentation tool are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by documentation tool?

Comment: Update: I'm using ReDoc: https://github.com/Redocly/redoc

Answer (score 0):

If the string value contains spaces (or some other special characters), you should enclose it in quotes. So the line should read

```
  example: "LeBron James"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried it out already, still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexIvanov Maybe there is an issue with the single quote in the next line? Did you try enclosing the description in quotes?

Comment: Updated the question.